# Domjudge keeps Not Authenticated

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to install Domjudge in my VPS. After I run `./configure`, `make` and `config database` I login at  `/public/login.php` with the user/pass: `judgehost/judge` but it doesn't log me in.

I try at `/jury` with user/pass: `admin/123456` and nothing happened too.

"judge" and "123456" is the right password because I change it in the database, if I type the wrong password, it will notice: "Invalid username or password supplied. Please try again or contact a staff member." so I thinks it not about the connection to the database or the wrong password.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: somebody help please :D

Comment: Please do not cross-post. (http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72043/domjudge-keeps-not-authenticated)